# C# CsvWriter throws "CsvWriter does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" after update from 2.8.4 to 27.1.1

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I updated the package for [`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) in my project from 2.8.4 to 27.1 & it looks like method I had been using has been updated.

It is now taking two more arguments.

I am not sure what `CsvConfiguration` or `CultureInfo` is, or what I need to do to correct this error.

`CsvWriter does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.`

The new methods:

```
public CsvWriter(TextWriter writer, CsvConfiguration configuration);

public CsvWriter(TextWriter writer, CultureInfo culture, bool leaveOpen = false);
```

My code:

```
using(var fs = new MemoryStream()) {
  using(var tx = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
    var csv = new CsvWriter(tx);
    csv.WriteHeader<TemplateCsvModel>();
    csv.WriteRecords(templates);
    csv.Dispose();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(fs.ToArray()).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to start with checking out their documentation on what's available and required for the configuration: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/. Unless you know you will need a special case, you can probably get away with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: Thanks in the System.Globalization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0) is needed to account for different formatting & parsings between various cultures as not everyone in the world formats dates, currency etc. the same.

If you don't need to parse your data based on the user's local settings, use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
using (var fs = new MemoryStream()) {
    using var tx = new StreamWriter(fs)
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(tx, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
        csv.WriteHeader<TemplateCsvModel>();
        csv.WriteRecords(templates);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(fs.ToArray()).ToArray();
      }
}
```